# Jquery how to cause action after image src is changed and loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

So I have a script that changes the main image src when a thumbnail is clicked on.  This is all good and well, except that occasionally the image doesn't load immediately when it is clicked on.

Essentially how do I know when the new image is loaded from the src change.

Here is the line of code I have that changes the source:

```
$thumbnail_image_src = $(this).find('.thumbnail-image').attr("data-full");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind a handler to the ['load'](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) event for the img tag ([this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghayes/rPZpf/8/))

```
 $(this).find('.thumbnail-image').each(function() {
   $(this).load(function() {
     alert('image has changed and loaded');
   })
   .error(function() {
     alert('image has failed to load');
   }).attr('src', $(this).attr('data-full'));
 });
```

These functions will fire at the appropriate events.  Enjoy!

Comment: I would have hoped so, but to be sure, I put a JSFiddle.

Comment: @ghayes yes, essentially the code is working.  I realized I was not quite asking the correct question for what I needed, but your post helped me find the right solutions.  Thanks again.

Comment: Yup, glad to be helpful.  The accuracy in the answer will hopefully help others that are struggling with the same issue later on in life.

Answer (score 1):

`img` tag has a `load` and `error` event which you can use to detect whether the image is loaded or not.

```
$("img").load(function(){
  //Image loaded
}).error(function(){
  //Image load failed
}).attr("src", $thumbnail_image_src);
```